# Autocomplete focus doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, frontend

I have an autocomplete input box. I want to display "x" link when I start to write something into input box. But it doesn't work. I don't know what is the mistake. 
Here are my codes and jsfiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/2mu2ht7g/

```
 <style>
 .icon-removeSearchItem{
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: -16px;
   display:none;
 }
</style>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
</script>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('input').focus(function(){
   if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';
   var value = $(this).val();
   if($('input').val().trim().length > 0 && value != "Add Comment"){
       $(".icon-removeSearchItem").show();
   }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.If you you are saying that you want to display limit number of values of search then you can use below code:-
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
        source: tags.slice(0, limit),

```
    });
```